# Dynamic generation- Multi Line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i'm using the following code for generating multi line graph. I'm getting the result. But the graph looks like:

[image]

```
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
  width = 1025 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 339 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
.range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

 var color = d3.scale.category10();

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");

  var line = d3.svg.line()  
.interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.days); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.testRuns); });

   var svg = d3.select("#application_status_graph").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.json("js/lineChartData.json", function(error, data) {
color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {return key !== "days"; }));
      data.forEach(function(d) {
     d.days = parseInt(d.days);
     });

     var status = color.domain().map(function(name){
return{
    name: name,
    values: data.map(function(d){
        return {days: d.days, testRuns: +d[name]};
    }) 
}
    });
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.days; }));

  y.domain([
      d3.min(status, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return    v.testRuns; }); }),
       d3.max(status, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.testRuns; }); })
        ]);
      svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
       .call(xAxis);

     svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
     .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
     .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
   .text("Number of Test Runs");

   var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
   .data(status)
   .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "city");

   city.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

   city.append("text")
  .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.days) + "," +       y(d.value.testRuns) + ")"; })
  .attr("x", 3)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    });
```

But i need it in this form:

[image]

I'm new to d3. The attribute which i'm using is line only for both. But it is coming as curves. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in var line = d3.svg.line()

```
.interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.days); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.testRuns); });
```

it should be changed to `.interpolate("linear")` to get the desired effect.
the wiki link explanes all types of line you can obtain:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_interpolate

hope this helps!